# how i design this type of layout is this button use in this layout ? to click it move other layout

Tags: android, android-xml

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVAIm.png)

I'm trying to do it with button  but they didn't work

```
<item android:bottom="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <!-- Set the background color of your layout here -->
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />`enter code here`
        </shape>
    </item>
```

Comment: Combination of TextView and View will do it.

Comment: Do u want a listView or custom ?

Comment: No i don't want in a listView .

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#5f06ef"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:background="#5f06ef"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:enter code herelayout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```